# Implementing String to int (atoi) in Java

Tags: java, parsing, interview-questions, reinventing-the-wheel, integer

> The function first discards as many whitespace characters as necessary until the first non-whitespace character is found. Then, starting from this character, takes an optional initial plus or minus sign followed by as many numerical digits as possible, and interprets them as a numerical value.
>
> The string can contain additional characters after those that form the integral number, which are ignored and have no effect on the behavior of this function.
>
> If the first sequence of non-whitespace characters in str is not a valid integral number, or if no such sequence exists because either str is empty or it contains only whitespace characters, no conversion is performed.
>
> If no valid conversion could be performed, a zero value is returned. If the correct value is out of the range of representable values, INT_MAX (2147483647) or INT_MIN (-2147483648) is returned.

I'm not sure about my checks against integer overflow, but here is my implementation:

```
public int myAtoi(String str) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < str.length() && Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i))) {
        ++i;
    }
    if (i == str.length()) {
        return 0;
    }

    boolean isNegative = false;
    if (str.charAt(i) == '+' || str.charAt(i) == '-') {
        isNegative = str.charAt(i) == '-';
        ++i;
    }

    int result = 0;
    while (i < str.length() && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
        try {
            result = Math.multiplyExact(result, 10);
            result = Math.addExact(result, Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i)));
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            return isNegative ? Integer.MIN_VALUE : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    if (isNegative) {
        result = -result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All in all, that's a pretty good implementation in a number of key details.

Using the `Character.isDigit()` and `Character.getNumericValue()` methods are good to see.

The `Math.*` methods that handle the overflow conditions are good too.

I am not sure if you intended it, but you also correctly handle an obscure edge-case in 32-bit signed integer systems (not just Java), where `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is not the same as `- Integer.MAX_VALUE` ... and your code actually gets it right for an exact input of the text "-2147483648"

So, you have good details in your code.... and I can't see any broken edge-cases.

My only recommendation would be that a state-machine may make things simpler... with just one loop..... but the state-machine may be a bit messy too, although I think it works out better in the long run...

```
public static int rlAtoi(String str) {
    boolean started = false;
    boolean negative = false;
    int result = 0;
    try {
        for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
            if (!started && Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                // great, ignore it.
            } else if (!started && (c == '+' || c == '-')) {
                // great, a sign
                negative = c == '-';
                started = true;
            } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                result = Math.multiplyExact(result, 10);
                result = Math.addExact(result, Character.getNumericValue(c));
                started = true;
            } else {
                // done....
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        return negative ? Integer.MIN_VALUE : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    return negative ? -result : result;
}
```

Note that in a raw performance benchmark, I suspect your solution will be (slightly) faster, but I prefer readability over small incremental performance gains, unless performance is extremely critical.

Comment: +1 for state machine, as this is much easier, almost always faster and much easier to debug / extend.

Answer (score 5):

There is a duplicate test for the '-' char. I'd rewrite

```
boolean isNegative = false;
if (str.charAt(i) == '+' || str.charAt(i) == '-') {
    isNegative = str.charAt(i) == '-';
    ++i;
}
```

as

```
boolean isNegative = false;
if (str.charAt(i) == '-') {
    isNegative= true;
    ++i;
    }
else if (str.charAt(i) == '+')
    ++i;
```

I would also add support for hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: A `switch` block would also work well here.

Comment: Ah, that's true. A `switch` with fall-through would probably have the least duplication.